Box layout unjustified preceding gap, how to fix?
In this example I use the Box class to organize components in a JPanel. My problem is the presence of an unjustified gap that shouldn't be there. Simply the text field should come at the beginning without the preceding gap. How to fix it?

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUIExample {

    private JPanel container;
    private JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3;
    private JSplitPane splitpane;

    public GUIExample() {
        container = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        tf1 = new JTextField();
        tf2 = new JTextField();
        tf3 = new JTextField();

        splitpane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
        splitpane.setDividerSize(3);
        splitpane.setDividerLocation(100);
        splitpane.setTopComponent(tf1);
        splitpane.setBottomComponent(tf2);
        
        Box boxContainer = Box.createVerticalBox();
        boxContainer.add(splitpane);
        boxContainer.add(tf3);

        container.add(boxContainer, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }


    protected JPanel getContainer() {
        return this.container;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            GUIExample gui = new GUIExample();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
            frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
            frame.add(gui.getContainer());
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.pack();
        });
    }
}


maybe adding the splitpane to another JPanel with BorderLayout (BTW it can be confusing, despite allowed, to use setTopComponent and setBottomComponent with HORIZONTAL_SPLIT)

The X alignment of the two components is different. You need to change the text field to align on the left to match the default left alignment of the split pane.
